# Formatting the y-axis

Tags: d3.js

I have a y axis which displays dollar values. I'm trying to find a single format strategy that works across all potential number ranges.

My current formatting strategy is `this.yAxis.tickFormat(d3.format('$.3s'))`

Here are some potential ranges and my issues with them

**Range: 1.4 billion - 4.5 billion**

Result:

[image]

Issue: Because i specified `3` sig figs, there is an unnecessary trailing zero for each tick. However when i switched to `2` sig figs, tick values like `750M` would be truncated to `700M`, which is not okay.

Ideal format: `1.5, 2.0, 2.5, 3.0, etc.`

---

**Range: 200 million - 2 billion:**

Result:

[image]

Issue: Axis should use the highest prefix for all ticks.

Ideal format: `0.5G, 1.0G, 1.5G, 2.0G`

---

**Range: 0 - 12 billion:**

Result:

[image]

Issue: Too many unnecessary trailing zeros.

Ideal format: `0G, 2G, 4G, 6G, 8G, 10G, 12G`

---

The general problem is that depending on the tick values and tick step, i either need to specify zero precision or some number of sig figs. I don't know how to write generic code to handle all these cases.